# Join column in dataframe to another dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. One has a bunch of columns including `f_uuid`. The other dataframe has 2 columns, `f_uuid` and `i_uuid`.

the first dataframe may contain some `f_uuid`s that the second dataframe doesn't and vice versa.

I want the first dataframe to have a new column `i_uuid` (from the second dataframe) populated with the appropriate values for the matching `f_uuid` in that first dataframe.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1,
               df2,
               on='f_uuid')
```

If you want to keep all f_uuid from df1 (e.g. those not available in df2), you may run

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1,
               df2,
               on='f_uuid',
               how='left')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is a merge : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge

In your case, that would look like :

```py
bunch_of_col_df.merge(other_df, on="f_uuid")
```